# Android GCM : issue with message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Google GCM for android exactly as written in this tutorial :
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

When sending message, BroadcastReceiver catch the Intent and call the GcmIntentService class :

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }
}
```

But in the 'sendNotification' method (in the Service class), "msg" is not the message I have sent, but something like :

```
Bundle[{android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=153438952475}]
```

My Service :

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.e(TAG,"GoogleCloudMessaging: error: "+ extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                Log.e(TAG,"GoogleCloudMessaging: deleted: "+ extras.toString());                
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification(extras.toString());
            }

        }

        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }


    private void sendNotification(String msg) {     
        GcmResult gcm = GcmResult.getGcm(msg);      
        GcmResultAsync async = new GcmResultAsync();
        async.setInfo(getApplicationContext(),gcm );
        async.execute();        
    }
}
```

*By the ways, all permissions are present.*

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Google example is a bit misleading, as it lumps all the extras into one. Exactly how you get your message out of the bundle depends on how you sent it. Whichever method you used, it will require you to get an ***'extra'*** out in the client.

Assuming you use PHP to send, then your data block might have looked like:

```
$fields = array(
           'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
             'data' => array( "message" => $message,
                              "moredata" => $morestuff),
             'delay_while_idle'=> false,
             'time_to_live' => 86400,
             'collapse_key'=>"".$randomNum.""
            );
```

where 'message' and 'moredata' are **keys** of my invention. To extract the **values** in the client you would have:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("message")) {
  String theMessage = intent.getStringExtra("message");
}
```

and

```
if (intent.hasExtra("moredata")) {
  String moreData = intent.getStringExtra("moredata");
}
```

You should be able to translate this code to make use of your own key/value pairs.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying ! Data in the server side  was wrong ! Thank you !

Comment: you saved from using a whole day working on this. I have two types of messages with two different keys now i was using the extra and it seems i had it wrong. by the way i used if(extra.haskey(stringkey) and works